# Another way to make the mouse click?

Tags: c#, winforms, dllimport

I am making an AI and want it to function as a player. I use some code to make the mouse click and this works. Then I made some code to make the mouse click on random places but then it stopped working.

I changed

```
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
```

to

```
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
```

but it did not seem to change anything except the location it pressed on.
I also made it wait 0,5 sec between mouseDown and mouseUp but it still did not work when I ran `rndPlay();`, when I tried to do just `press1();` it did work.

```
        public static void MoveTo(int x, int y)
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0, 0);
        }

        public static void LeftClick()
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition.X, System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition.Y, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition.X, System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition.Y, 0, 0);
        }
        public static void LeftMouseClick(int x, int y)
        {
            MoveTo(x, y);
            LeftClick();

        }

        public static void press1()
        {
            LeftMouseClick(28000, 25000);
            last2Moves("1");
        }
        public static void press2()
        {
            LeftMouseClick(33000, 25000);
            last2Moves("2");
        }
        //etc

        public static void rndPlay()
        {
            for (int r = 0; moveSucces != true && r < 10000; r++)
            {

                Random rndP = new Random();
                int rndPress = rndP.Next(1, 10);
                if (rndPress == 1)
                {
                    press1();
                }
                if (rndPress == 2)
                {
                    press2();
                }
                    //etc
             }
         }
```

When I run `rndPlay();` I see the mouse move but it does not seem to click. Is there another way to make the mouse click in a location that would work better/faster?

Comment: Consider [`WM_MOUSEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), the lParam parameter determines the mouse position. The low-order word specifies the x-coordinate and the high-order word specifies the y-coordinate of the cursor. Using 16 bit for x and 16 bit for y means it can not handle coordinates larger that 32767.

Comment: Your mouse coordinates seem very big.

Comment: @Phil1970  When `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` is specified, the mouse relative position is expressed in twips, in a normalized, device independent, `(65535,65535)` coordinate system. The standard screen coordinates need to be converted/normalized when reading/writing to the function, calculating the TwipsPerPixelX/Y values. One may want to use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead. `mouse_event` has been in a `deprecated` state for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using very large values for X and Y your code seems ok.
I whipped up a small example using a `textbox` to show when and where the mouse was clicked, connected to a simple `Forms` timer to simulate clicks.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

   private const int MouseLeftDown = 0x02;
   private const int MouseLeftUp = 0x04;

   private readonly Timer _timer = new Timer();

   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      _timer.Interval = 1000;
      _timer.Tick += (s, a) => mouse_event(MouseLeftDown | MouseLeftUp, (uint)MousePosition.X, (uint)MousePosition.Y, 0, 0);
      _timer.Enabled = true;

      _textBox.Click += (s, a) => _textBox.AppendText($"Clicked at {PointToClient(MousePosition)}\n");
   }
}
```